# Firebase events and parameters in lowercase

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I am currently setting up some tracking requirements.
Is it a problem for Firebase Analytics auto-tracking if Firebase events and parameters are in lowercase instead of uppercase?

Example

This

```
mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent( Event.VIEW_SEARCH_RESULTS, ecommerceBundle );
```

To

```
mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent( Event.view_search_results, ecommerceBundle );
```

Answer (score 1):

There will not be any problem. The Analytics backend would automatically convert the uppercase into lowercase while displaying on the console.